# how to retrieve official business' photo from google places?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-api

I am new at using Google Api 'I manage to retrieve businesss from google place but the only photos I could get are photos uploaded by customers 
Is there a way to retrieve the official photo/Logo of the business? 
thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use [place ID](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) that uniquely identifies a place and can be used to retrieve information about the place. It looks like `ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0`.

> Place IDs are available for most locations, including businesses, landmarks, parks, and intersections. These IDs are stable, meaning that once you've identified the place ID for a place, you can reuse that value when you next look up that place.

When the Places service returns results from a details request, it places them within a single `result`. Each result within the results array may contain the `photos[]` field:

```
"photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 242,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAABjeoPQ7NUU3pDitV4Vs0BgP1FLhf_iCgStUZUr4ZuNqQnc5k43jbvjKC2hTGM8SrmdJYyOyxRO3D2yutoJwVC4Vp_dzckkjG35L6LfMm5sjrOr6uyOtr2PNCp1xQylx6vhdcpW8yZjBZCvVsjNajLBIQ-z4ttAMIc8EjEZV7LsoFgRoU6OrqxvKCnkJGb9F16W57iIV4LuM",
               "width" : 200
            }
```

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462253/how-to-get-a-picture-of-a-place-from-google-maps-or-places-api) and [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) for more details.

Comment: I did get the photo array, my problem is that in this array all the photos are photos taken by customers and uploaded (its could be a photo of a meal) but I want to display a list of business with their "official" photo or logo and I didnt find that in the google object  or docs