# Google Places API - How to get the mini map with two photos like so?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

Google Places API - How to get the mini map with two photos like so?
[image]

But, a part of the image was missing. Can anyone guide me?

I only can get the bitmap image left side part, but it missing the right side part of the photo with Google text.

The guide: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/photos

Comment: Not able to see image. Please update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways you can put a map next to the photo:

1. Use a [MapView object from the Android Maps API SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map).
2. Use the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/) to request a map bitmap via HTTP.

Comment: Yes. This is what I wanted. Thank you so much!! :D :D

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as Answered by ticking the green check button :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is that you try the [Place Photo Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) HTTP request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?parameters
```

sample:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You might also want to try this answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462253/how-to-get-a-picture-of-a-place-from-google-maps-or-places-api) using the Panoramio API.

Comment: Hi Noogui,
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi Noogui,

Thanks for the answer.

Actually, I want the part of Map atlas with Google text, not the place photo. I mean I want right side part, not the left side part.
Can you tell me more about that? Thank you!!

Comment: I though the API is very handy to use. Upset!

Comment: just feel It not perfect at all.

Comment: Some features are not directly supported by API. Try [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231403/how-to-take-google-maps-v2-snapshot) . You can always make your own implementation.

Comment: It Let user see the photos on the dialog, but cannot get what it has. Disappointed!

Comment: The SupportMapFragment is no longer in the latest SDK already.

Comment: Anyway Thanks for the reply!